# Usare due apostrofi in un'unica stringa

Tags: grammar, punctuation, apocope

Cari amici,

secondo il vostro qualificato parere, è corretto usare due apostrofi in una stringa?

Per esempio:

> - I buonisti dell'ultim'ora.
> - 'st'ultima volta. (dove "'st" abbrevia "quest")

La stringa nel primo caso è «dell'ultim'ora» e nel secondo è «'st'ultima».

Comment: Li usava Dante. Non vedo perché non potresti tu, in particolare se, come nel secondo esempio, vuoi riportare una più accurata riproduzione del parlato.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usare due apostrofi è lecito, ma rendono meno scorrevole la lettura. L'[elisione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisione) si utilizza più nella lingua parlata che nella lingua scritta. Dove non è indispensabile credo sia meglio evitarla.

Per riproporre i tuoi esempi, credo che suonerebbero meglio così:

> I buonisti dell'ultima ora.

o,nel secondo caso, eliminando entrambi gli apostrofi:

> questa ultima volta.

Considerata la discussione che è emersa, integro la risposta citando un articolo dell'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/elisione-troncamento-nellitaliano-contempora) nel quale si spiega come diversi linguisti propendano alla conservazione dell'interezza della parola dove non è necessario un troncamento:

> fenomeno, già da tempo riscontrato nell'italiano contemporaneo: la
>   tendenza al regresso delle forme tronche ed elise rispetto alle forme
>   piene delle parole.

Comment: Concordo con te, Walter. Un altro esempio per Elberich potrebbe essere "l'altr'anno", meglio traducibile in "l'anno scorso" o "lo scorso anno" nella lingua scritta.

Comment: Non vedo perché dovrebbe essere poco scorrevole dire _dell'ultim'ora_, scorre altrettanto bene che dire _dell'ultima ora_, con la differenza che, essendo _l'ultim'ora_ un modo di dire va scritto proprio in questo modo. Mi lascia anche perplesso la teoria che l'elisione sia poco usata nella lingua scritta; questo è vero in inglese ma in italiano essendo l'apostrofo obbligatorio in almeno un caso importante cioè l'articolo determinativo (non è che posso scrivere _lo apostrofo_) direi che sia "sdoganato" in tutti i casi. Quando "suona male" è perché suona male anche pronunciato.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @MauroVanetti: chi dice (a parte la Wikipedia) che l'elisione sia più del parlato che dello scritto?

Comment: (Comunque i dibattiti tra italofoni su cosa "suona male" sono stupendi. :-) )

Comment: Walter, non trovo nella pagina della Crusca che citi la parte in cui si mostra la propensione di diversi linguisti per le forme non tronche.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo me è giusto e può essere usato senza nessun problema. Non vedo differenze tra lingua scritta e parlata rispetto all'apostrofo.

Il primo esempio ha un suono assolutamente normale. Il secondo esempio fatto è brutto e non verrebbe usato né nella lingua parlata né in quella scritta, ma non perché ci siano due apostrofi: infatti anche *'sta ultima volta* ha un suono cattivo. Diremmo semmai *quest'ultima volta*.

In generale l'elisione di *questo* in *'sto*, che suona sempre leggermente dialettale o colloquiale fuori da certe espressioni codificate (che non vogliono più l'apostrofo: *stavolta*, *stasera*), non può essere applicata con la stessa noncuranza con cui si elide la vocale finale di molte parole. Noto che talvolta gli stranieri abusano di questa elisione appena la imparano, confondendola con altre elisioni più diffuse (come *che cos'è*) o addirittura quasi obbligatorie (come *l'albero*).

Comment: Un esempio della Marchesa Colombi (pseudonimo di Maria Antonietta Torriani), tratto dal romanzo *Un matrimonio in provincia*: «Inoltre si occuperà un poco di voi, che ora siete grandi, ed avete bisogno **d'un'assistenza**, che la zia non saprebbe prestarvi...»

Answer (score 1):

Buon giorno.

Non è un errore usare 2 apostrofi in una sola stringa, ma è raro. E, come per tutte le cose rare, non bisogna usarlo continuamente altrimenti diventa "pesante" per chi legge.

Answer (score -1):

Sì, è corretto, come anche: un'altr'ora, un'altr'onda ... corretti, ma - scritti e oggi - sono semplicemente terribili.
Parlando di Dante (meraviglioso), mia nonna diceva l'oriolo, invece di orologio, ma oggi sarebbe davvero brutto.